# I want a UK Standard Visitor visa but I am travelling alone

Tags: visas, uk, solo-travel

I am 20 years old and want to go to UK from India for a wedding. My relatives have sent me a sponsor form, their passport copy, tax bill, water bill and bank statement and I am going to stay in their home but my agent is saying that it's hard to get a visa because of travelling alone.

Is he right, and what document should I give them to prove that I can travel alone, or is there nothing to worry about?

Comment: What documents do you intend to give to prove you will return back ? That is a very very important point to ponder on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @DumbCoder mentioned, the burden of proof is on you to show that you have an strong and valid `intention to leave`. This could include things such as family back home (spouse and/or children), a large bank account, a really good job, some combination of the above, or something else that ties you to your home and offers a compelling reason why you would leave the UK and go back.

Immigration officials are very wary of young solo travelers (especially young women), because they often don't have strong ties back home and thus sometimes have very strong incentives to overstay their visas.

As a further example, this is from a [recently archived Home Office form](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/423975/General_visitor_V15.0EXT.pdf) (note the first listed item in particular):

> **Grounds for doubting the applicant’s genuine intentions to visit the UK**
>  This is not an exhaustive list but may help with your
>   assessment:
>
> - the applicant has few or no family and economic ties to their country of residence, and has several family members in the UK
> - the political, economic and security situation in the applicant’s country of residence, including whether it is politically unstable, a
>     conflict zone or at risk of becoming one, which may lead to doubts
>     about their intention to leave the UK at the end of their visit
> - the applicant, their sponsor (if they are visiting a friend or relative) or other immediate family member has, or has attempted to,
>     deceive the Home Office in a previous application for entry clearance,
>     leave to enter or leave to remain
> - there are discrepancies between the statements made by the applicant and the statements made by the sponsor, particularly on points where
>     the sponsor could reasonably be expected to know the facts but does
>     not
> - it has not been possible to verify information provided by the applicant despite repeated attempts to do so
> - the information that has been provided or the reasons stated by the applicant are not credible.

So your best bet is to find as many reasons as possible for why you would return to your home country, document them, and provide those documents to the immigration officer.

Good luck!

Comment: i am male,you said that i will need to prove them that i will come back in my country so i am showing my college document that proves that i am doing my graduation and i am visiting their country in my holidays what documents should i show them to prove that my parents are here and i will come back.i am visiting their country for my sister wedding for 20 days.

Comment: Are you parents paying for you college? If so, showing documents proving that would probably be helpful. Also, maybe show a copy of your parents identification (assuming it has residency information on it). I can't give any legal advice here - just ideas. every immigration officer is different.

Comment: @naman documentation of your studies and that your parents are supporting you and that your parents are in the same country all work in your favor, I believe.  If you graduate shortly before your trip, however, that would be a concern for the immigration officer.  If your finances are weak, as most students' are, and if your parents' finances are strong, it might be a good idea to say that your parents are paying for your trip, and to submit their bank statements, etc., in support of your application.

Comment: bonafide certificate,leave letter and Noc from my college will prove that i will return back to my home country and i am also showing that my parents live here i think it will be enough to prove that i will come back to my home country